# Passing string with apostrophe to helper method doesn't display correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I'm using a helper method from the rails tutorial which concatenates two strings together for use in the title selector in the view. It works perfectly fine, unless there is an apostrophe in the string.

When :group_name contains an apostrophe it comes out like this:

```
<title>The website | O&amp;#x27;Malley Brothers</title>
```

Here is the method: app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Chicago Improv Festival"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how it's used in the layout view. app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

Here is where the :title is set in another view file: app/views/submissions/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @submission.group_name) %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `.html_safe` so the apostrophe isn't escaped.

```
"#{base_title} | #{page_title}".html_safe
```

Comment: This is safe against html injection?

Comment: It seems to rely on the database sanitizer to prevent someone from dropping "</title><script>evil</script>" as their user name and exploiting the page.

Comment: @KevinM, this is not a good answer as it's a security risk. Can you accept my answer instead? It's important that people don't copy this example.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad idea to call `.html_safe` willy nilly. Unless you have full control over `base_title` and `page_title` then you're opening yourself up to an attack, though I'm not sure what kind of attacks can exploit the `<title></title>` tag.

I had the same problem. The solution was not to use string interpolation, instead:

```
base_title + ' | ' + page_title
```