# Apostrophe Appearing as "&#39;" in Title Tab of Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, title, apostrophe

Apostrophes are appearing as "'" in the title tabs of my Rails application. Everywhere else the apostrophes appear correctly. How may I correct this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the apostrophe to appear as `'` or as `&#39;`.

If you put your apostrophe in double quoted strings then it will render correctly:

```
<title><%="example 'title'" %></title> #=> example 'title'
```

If you put `&#39;` inside double quoted strings then it will be returned as it is written.

```
<title><%="example &#39;title&#39;" %></title> #=> example &#39;title&#39;
```

Finally, if you want to use `&#39;` and have it parsed correctly then you can use `raw`.

```
<title><%=raw "example &#39;title&#39;" %></title> #=> example 'title'
```

If it is not working as expected then it may be a browser issue, however, I have tested with modern versions of Firefox and Safari and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

To help those with their "Google Fu".

If you are here because you are doing the rails title on every page like [SO: rails-how-to-change-the-title-of-a-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185965/rails-how-to-change-the-title-of-a-page) and have records where your apostrophe is appearing with the &#39 and simply want it with an ' (ie `My Dog's Pants` instead of `My Dog&#39s Pants`) then you can checkout this answer that uses ruby string interpolation `#{}` and `.html_safe`.

[Passing string with apostrophe to helper method doesn't display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052484/passing-string-with-apostrophe-to-helper-method-doesnt-display-correctly/13052550)

As an example, I put a method in my `post.rb` model:

```
  def page_title
    "#{ id.to_s +  " - " + name }".html_safe
  end
```

Then in my `posts_controller.rb` I have:

```
@title = @post.page_title
```

Then in my `application.html.erb` I have:

```
<body>
  <title><%= ("Post - " + yield(:title) + " - " unless yield(:title).blank?).to_s + "jaykilleen.com" %></title>
</body>
```

Then in my `show.html.erb` for posts I have:

```
<% content_for :title, @title if @title.present? %>
```

Comment: Instead of using `html_safe`, which can be dangerous on user content, like the Name of an Account, etc. Use `sanitize( yield( :title ) )`. It will render the apostrophe correctly as well as remove any dangerous XSS code.